# Transaction with RollBack in mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, phpmyadmin

By Creating this `Strored` `Procedure` i am getting error dont know how to fix it

Here is my sql

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Sp_Reservation;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE Sp_Reservation
(
 IN name VARCHAR(150),
 IN email VARCHAR(100),
 IN mobile VARCHAR(15),
 IN cninc VARCHAR(15),
 IN cityID INT(10),
 IN checkin Date,
 IN checkout Date,
 IN noOfRooms INT(5),
 IN RoomID INT(10),
 IN RoomCategoryID INT(10),
 IN noOfChilds INT(5),
 IN noOfAdults INT(5),
 IN message VARCHAR(500),
 IN reservationStatus vARCHAR(10)
)
BEGIN
DECLARE CusID INT DEFAULT 1;

DECLARE EXIT HANDLER FOR SQLEXCEPTION
BEGIN
ROLLBACK;
END;
START TRANSACTION;
BEGIN

SET CusID =( 
SELECT 
 IF(Max(customers.CustomerID) IS NULL,CUstID,customers.CustomerID) as
 CutomID FROM customers);

INSERT  INTO `customers` (customers.CustomerName,
                          customers.CustomerNID,
                          customers.CustomerEmail,
                          customers.CutomerMobile,
                          customers.CityID)
                VALUES(name,
                       cnic,
                       email,
                       Mobile,
                       CityID);

INSERT  INTO    `roomreservation`(roomreservation.CustomerID,
                                    roomreservation.RoomID,
                                  roomreservation.CheckIn,
                                  roomreservation.CheckOut,
                                  roomreservation.NoOfAdults,
                                  roomreservation.NoOfChildrens,
                                  roomreservation.Message,
                                  roomreservation.ReservationStatus)

SELECT  1,RoomID,checkin,checkout,noOfAdults,noOfChilds,message,reservationStatus
FROM rooms WHERE RoomID NOT IN
(
SELECT RoomID FROM roomreservation WHERE  ReservationStatus = 'Reserved'

AnD roomreservation.CheckIn BETWEEN checkIn AND   checkout
 ) ;
-- LIMIT (noOfRooms);

COMMIT;
END;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

ERROR:

**SQL query:**

DELIMITER ;

**MySQL said:**

> ## 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'DELIMITER' at line 1.

**Note:** I am using Phpmyadmin

Comment: Phpmyadmin is buggy use some other client

Comment: @Mihai There is something wrong with my procedure ?

Comment: I dont think so,but AFAIK phpmyadmin cant deal with multiple statements and delimiter changes.Maybe you have that END twice

Comment: You should try to enter the statements one after another. `First DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS Sp_Reservation;` then `DELIMITER $$` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I don't see any issue with your procedure code except that you can try changing the statement `END$$` to `END $$`. If still doesn't work then there is problem with your `Phpmyadmin` client and somehow it's not happy with the statement `DELIMITER $$`. Try using a different client (or) a different version of current client.